# Error expected type StringIO, got str instead

Tags: python, io, psycopg2, stringio

I'm trying to bulk insert data into my postgres database using the copy_from function from psycopg2.
To use this function, I'm trying to put a list of tuples into a file-like object using io.StringIO (python 3.x).

```
    def __insert_cpe_dic__(self, cpe_dic):
        sio = StringIO
        sio.write('\n'.join(cpe for cpe in cpe_dic))
        sio.seek(0)
        self.cur.copy_from(sio, "cpe_dictionary")
```

I get the error: 'expected type StringIO, got str instead ...'
when writing to the 'sio' variable.
I couldn't find any answer to my problem and hope someone has an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned a class not an instance of a class when you did `sio = StringIO`. You need to add parens to instantiate an instance of the class: `sio = StringIO()`. Also, you don't need the explicit generator, just doing `sio.write('\n'.join(cpe_dic))` will produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes I miss such simple things and wonder what's wrong.